# availability of high multiple leveraged ETF in developed world

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, european-union, leveraged-etf

Is there any country or exchange where highly leveraged ( such as 5X, 8X or 10X ( instead of 3X) ETF/ETN are available for trade. I remember seeing something like this in news but could not locate anything further than [5X](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/5SPY.L/).

I understand that leveraged products are not suitable for everyone's risk profile. My question is about availability.

I am not asking for product, but asking for markets ( like USA, Europe ) where it is available.

Comment: BULL Nasdaq-100 Index® X8 at https://beursproducten.vontobel.com/NL/EN/Product/DE000VN61Y14

Comment: SE0009861198 per http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/etp/etn/etninfo?Instrument=SSE138174

Comment: You could probably get a similar leverage effect by using options on ETFs or index futures.

Comment: Related: [Geared ETFs - Do they offer more than 3x leverage?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/28453/geared-etfs-do-they-offer-more-than-3x-leverage)

Comment: @flux thanks for the link of the other question